# Can I use dot navigation when using multiple parameters to filter (compare) in SQL SELECT?

Tags: sql, json, sql-server, t-sql, open-json

I new in SQL, I want to retrieve only the records of a certain `groupID` and I am using this query:

```
SELECT @Date, Capacity, UserOrUserGroup 
FROM UCTimePhaseMonthly 
WHERE Date >= 2023-05-01 
  AND UserOrUserGroup.id = '/User/fdwr6cs6msxapw5zh4bh5jj93'
```

Above an example of just one return object.

```
 [
    {
        "id": "/UCTimePhaseMonthly/2z1r4vdk3d8qk16uegexx5rxx3453",
        "Date": "2023-06-01T00:00:00.0000000",
        "Capacity": {
            "unit": "Hours",
            "value": 176
        },
        "UserOrUserGroup": {
            "id": "/User/fdwr6cs6msxapw5zh4bh5jj93"
        }
    }    
 ]
```

If the field `id` is nested inside `UserOrUserGroup`, can I use dot navigation when using multiple parameters to filter (compare) in SQL `SELECT`?

Comment: Take a peek at ...   JSON_VALUE()

Comment: Does the outer array ever have more than one object in it, per row?

Comment: @Charlieface yes it has a lot (+500), I copy only one for here

Comment: @mrbangybang  Try   json_value(YourJSON,'$[0].UserOrUserGroup.id')

Comment: Looking at Charlie's question, you may need to look into OPENJSON()

Comment: Be careful with your date predicates. Date and datetime datatypes can be a little misleading sometimes. When you use 2023-05-01 it is NOT going to be the date you think. It will instead be July 11, 1905 which is 2017 days after 1/1/1900. That is the result of the integer equation 2023-05-01. You need to use single quotes around date literals, and ideally in YYYYMMDD format. So something like >= '20230501'.

Answer (score 1):

Since you have an array, you need to use `OPENJSON`. You can do it inside an `EXISTS`

```sql
SELECT
  @Date,
  tpm.Capacity,
  tpm.UserOrUserGroup
FROM UCTimePhaseMonthly tpm
WHERE Date >= '20230501'
  AND EXISTS (SELECT 1
    FROM OPENJSON(tpm.UserOrUserGroup)
      WITH (
        id varchar(100) '$.UserOrUserGroup.id'
      ) j
    WHERE j.id = '/User/fdwr6cs6msxapw5zh4bh5jj93'
);
```

Or you can pull out the actual value

```sql
SELECT
  @Date,
  tpm.Capacity,
  tpm.UserOrUserGroup,
  j.id
FROM UCTimePhaseMonthly tpm
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(tpm.UserOrUserGroup)
WITH (
  id varchar(100) '$.UserOrUserGroup.id'
) j
WHERE Date >= '20230501'
  AND j.id = '/User/fdwr6cs6msxapw5zh4bh5jj93';
```

Note that dates need to go in quotes.